# Is there a way to sort only the selected columns in an Excel Pivot Table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I want to have the first three columns locked due to the nature of the values, but when I sort horizontally, the columns I don't want sorted end up in the middle of the chart. Is there a way around this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe this a bit more? Is this a vba function to sort them and the unprotected columns all sort and the protected are just tacked on the end? If its like that I would probably unprotect, sort then reprotect the columns. But hard to say based on the info you have given

Comment: @BenRhys-Lewis No, not VBA as of yet, just **Sort - Largest to Smallest - left to right**.  This causes all columns in the selected row to be sorted, which is unwanted. I'm looking for a way to horizontally sort the selected columns, which seems to be disallowed by the nature of the pivot table, whether it's in Excel itself or VBA. Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA function it would proabbly look something like this then:

```
Sub SortLTable()
    Range("D2:G10").Sort Key1:=Range("D1:G1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight
End Sub
```

Where the range is obviously what you want to sort and key determines the values to be sorted

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this doesn't work. I have thought of a work around however, so I'm going to give it a shot.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Obviously the ranges will need to change to fit but if post your code and I can take a look.

Comment: Never mind, there was an error on my end, but I ended up fixing it. Thanks for the help.